# Multiple visibility outputs from a if statements adobe animate html5

Tags: createjs

Thank you for your time
I have a large animation I am working on with several if statements with many outputs
I join the outputs with & ampersand and it all works ok, but when I try to call the visibility of a movie clip, it will not work. Here is a simple one I wrote using three movie clips.

```
this.black_sw.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToHide.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToHide()
{ if(this.black_mc. visible== true)(

    this.black_mc.visible = false 

    this.redball.visible = true
    )
    else if(this.black_mc. visible== false)

        (this.black_mc.visible = true

    this.redball.visible = false)
}
```

This does not work console error if I add a "&" to join the statements also console error,  deleting
one of the (visible = ) conditions in each part, it works, why, I am stumped.

best regards peter

Answer (score 0):

```
this.black_sw.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToHide.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToHide()
{
    if (this.black_mc.visible)
    {
        this.black_mc.visible = false
        this.redball.visible = true
    }
    else
    {
        this.black_mc.visible = true
        this.redball.visible = false
    }


}
```

This should work